# How can I log all imports that are executed in a block of code?

Tags: python

I'm writing a test suite, and the code I'm testing makes excessive use of delayed module imports.  So it's possible that with 5 different inputs to the same method, this may end up importing 5 additional modules.  What I'd like to be able to do is set up tests so that I can assert that running the method with one input causes one import, and doesn't cause the other 4.

I had a few ideas of how to start on this, but none so far have been successful.  I already have a custom importer, and I can put the logging code in the importer.  But this doesn't work, because the import statements only run once.  I need the log statement to be executed regardless of if the module has been previously imported.  Just running `del sys.modules['modname']` also doesn't work, because that runs in the test code, and I can't reload the module in the code being tested.

The next thing I tried was subclassing `dict` to do the monitoring, and replace sys.modules with this subclass.  This subclass has a reimplemented `__getitem__` method, but calling `import module` doesn't seem to trigger the `__getitem__` call in the subclass.  I also can't assign directly to `sys.modules.__getitem__`, because it is read-only.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

**UPDATE**

nneonneo's answer seems to only work if the implementation of `logImports()` is in the same module as where it is used.  If I make a base test class containing this functionality, it has problems.  The first is that it can't find just `__import__`, erroring with:

```
#     old_import = __import__
# UnboundLocalError: local variable '__import__' referenced before assignment
```

When I change that to `__builtin__.__import__`, I another error:

myunittest.py:

```
import unittest
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def logImports(self):
        old_import = __builtins__.__import__
        def __import__(*args, **kwargs):
            print args, kwargs
            return old_import(*args, **kwargs)

        __builtins__.__import__ = __import__
```

test.py:

```
import myunittest
import unittest
class RealTest(myunittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.logImports()
    def testSomething(self):
        import unittest
        self.assertTrue(True)
unittest.main()

#     old_import = __builtins__.__import__
# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__import__'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
old_import = __import__
def __import__(*args, **kwargs):
    print args, kwargs
    return old_import(*args, **kwargs)

__builtins__.__import__ = __import__
```

This overrides `__import__` completely, allowing you to monitor every invocation of `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer, in Python 3, I've had success with the following.

```
import builtins
old_import = __import__

def importWithLog(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args[0]) # This is the module name
    print(args, kwargs)
    return old_import(*args, **kwargs)

builtins.__import__ = importWithLog

# Rest of the code goes here.
import time
import myModule
...
```

Comment: Why does the code work in this way? Please explain it so that your answer can be more useful.